# $\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{x+z}+\frac{z^2}{x+y} \ge \frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, tangent-line-method

let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers 
$$\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{x+z}+\frac{z^2}{x+y} \ge \frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)$$

then how to prove above by Cauchy Schwarz  -Inquality

Comment: @AlexFrancisco...no its not i am asking by cauchy inquality

Comment: Well for a fact in general the Titu's lemma is proved by the Cauchy Schwarz only.  So Titu's lemma is indirectly the same as Cauchy Schwarz for some special cases.

Comment: This is a bit similar : [Prove that $\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2}{b+c}+\frac{c^2}{c+a}\geq\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)$ for positive $a,b,c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264931/prove-that-fraca2ab-fracb2bc-fracc2ca-geq-frac12abc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard fact that $a^{2}+b^{2}\geq 2ab$ for $a,b\geq 0$ follows by C-S: Consider $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$, then $2ab=(a,b)\cdot(b,a)\leq\|(a,b)\|\cdot\|(b,a)\|=a^{2}+b^{2}$.

Now we have $\dfrac{a^{2}}{b}\geq 2a-b$ and we put $a=2x$ and $b=y+z$ we get
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(2x)^{2}}{y+z}\geq 4x-y-z.
\end{align*}
Doing this in the symmetric fashion we get
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(2x)^{2}}{y+z}+\dfrac{(2y)^{2}}{x+z}+\dfrac{(2z)^{2}}{x+y}\geq 4(x+y+z)-2(x+y+z)=2(x+y+z).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

By C-S:
$$\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{x+z}+\frac{z^2}{x+y}\ge \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{y+z+x+z+x+y}=\frac{x+y+z}{2}.$$

Comment: @Manthanein..yes i am same dougt ...

Comment: @farruhota..this is titu's lemma

Answer (score 2):

Also, SOS helps: $$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^2}{y+z}-\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{x(x-y-(z-x))}{y+z}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)\left(\frac{x}{y+z}-\frac{y}{x+z}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)^2(x+y+z)}{(x+z)(y+z)}\geq0.$$

Solution by Tangent Line method.

Since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume $x+y+z=3$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{3-x}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^2}{3-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-1)(2x+3)}{3-x}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(x-1)(2x+3)}{3-x}-\frac{5}{2}(x-1)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-1)^2}{3-x}\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well now I got it.

Consider the two sets of real numbers 
$${\frac {x}{\sqrt {y+z}}, \frac {y}{\sqrt {x+z}}, \frac {z}{\sqrt {y+x}}}$$

and $${\sqrt {y+z}, \sqrt {x+z},\sqrt {y+x}}$$ 
Now using CS we get 
$$\left(\frac {x^2}{y+z}+ \frac {y^2}{x+z}+ \frac {z^2}{y+x}\right)\left(2(x+y+z)\right)  \ge {(x+y+z)}^2$$

Hence we get

$$\left(\frac {x^2}{y+z}+ \frac {y^2}{x+z}+ \frac {z^2}{y+x}\right) \ge \frac{x+y+z}{2}$$

Q. E. D

Answer (score 1):

**Proof 1**: Another quite well known proof to this classic problem is as follows: WLOG assume $x+y+z = 1$ and this is possible since you can rewrite the left side of the inequality as $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyclic}}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{x}{x+y+z}\right)^2}{\dfrac{y}{x+y+z}+\dfrac{z}{x+y+z}}\ge \dfrac{1}{2}$. With the assumption $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyclic}} x = 1$ in mind, the inequality becomes: $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyclic}} \dfrac{x^2}{1-x} \ge \dfrac{1}{2}$. To this end, consider $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{1-x} = -1-x-\dfrac{1}{x-1}$, and $f''(x)=\dfrac{2}{(1-x)^3}>0$. Thus $f$ is convex, and $LHS = \displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyclic}} f(x)\ge 3f\left(\dfrac{x+y+z}{3}\right)=3f\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=3\times \dfrac{1}{6} = \dfrac{1}{2}$ as claimed. **Note**: the word "cyclic" can be removed, but I still put it there because majority of problems similar to this one can be written nicely with the short cut using the word "cyclic".

**Proof 2**: This is probably what OP is craving for...since it is simple and easy to see...To this end again, use the same assumption in proof 1 above and the function $f(x) = -1-x +\dfrac{1}{1-x}$. Thus using AM-GM inequality: $LHS = f(x)+f(y)+f(z) = (-1-x+\dfrac{1}{1-x})+(-1-y+\dfrac{1}{1-y})+(-1-z+\dfrac{1}{1-z})= \dfrac{1}{y+z}+\dfrac{1}{x+z}+\dfrac{1}{x+y}-4\ge \dfrac{9}{(x+y)+(y+z)+(z+x)}-4=\dfrac{9}{2}-4 = \dfrac{1}{2}$. **Note**: This can be done by using the Angel Form of the CS inequality, but we view it as a AM-GM inequality for we applied it twice.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

We have:
$$LHS -RHS=\frac{x^2}{y+z} +\frac{y^2}{z+x} +\frac{z^2}{x+y}-\frac{x+y+z}{2}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{cyc}(\frac{x^2}{y+z} -x +\frac{y+z}{4})$$

$$=\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{(y+z-2x)^2}{4(y+z)} \geq 0$$

Equality holds when $x=y=z$

qed.

Or another way!

$$LHS -RHS =\frac{x^2}{y+z} +\frac{y^2}{z+x} +\frac{z^2}{x+y} -\frac{x+y+z}{2}$$

$$=[\frac{x^2}{y+z} +\frac{y^2}{z+x}-\frac{(x+y)^2}{x+y+2z}] +[\frac{(x+y)^2}{x+y+2z}+\frac{z^2}{x+y} -\frac{x+y+z}{2}]$$

$$=\frac{(x-y)^2 (x+y+z)^2}{(x+z)(y+z)(x+y+2z)} +\frac{(x+y-2z)^2(x+y+z)}{2(x+y)(x+y+2z)} \geq 0$$

qed.

P.s: I don't certainly about my answer, can you check it?